# How to exclude param from response in struts 2 and send the object we want?

Tags: java, ajax, json, struts2, gson

I want JSON result for Ajax request, but my requirement is to send only the `ArrayList` of object and exclude some of the parameter present in action class. So how to do this?

This is my action class

```
public class AjaxAction{
    private  int color;
    private  String prodId;
    private List<Product> productList;
   
 
    public String execute(){
    productList= service.getProductList();//this method is getting list of products
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(productList,
            new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {
            }.getType());
    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    try {
        response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}
```

And my `struts.xml` file is:

```xml
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="mystack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <action name="getProduct" class="com.xyz.action.AjaxAction">
        <result name="success" type="json" />
        <param name="root">productList</param>
    </action>
</package>
```

So when i check my console data returned from action is having other variable in it. How to avoid that?

Comment: You would use the [Struts2-json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html) and the  `root` property. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `stream` result

```xml
<action name="getProduct" class="com.xyz.action.AjaxAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

and in the action

```
private InputStream inputStream;

//getter here
public InputStream getInputStream () {
  return inputStream;
}


public String execute(){
  productList= service.getProductList();//this method is getting list of products

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(productList,
        new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {
        }.getType());
  JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
  inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonArray.toString().getBytes());
  return "success";
}
```